# Add text to the file if exist and create file with text if not in java

Tags: java, javafx, html-editor

I need add text to existing file from (if user choose file at the begining - PUSH READ BUTTON)

```
fileread = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
```

Or if file doesn't exist(user don't choose file at the begining from read button), the same SAVE button , open a

```
 File filesave = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(primaryStage);
```

And save file as always, if user nothing choose.

I have method savefield - which save text from HTMLEditor javaFX

```
@FXML public void savefiled() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
      Stage primaryStage = null;
      String stringHtml = HTMLEditor_go.getHtmlText();

if(fileread.getPath().equals("")||fileread.getPath() == null){ //this line gives me a NULL

    Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("./src/path/my_text/"));
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("HTML files (*.html)", "*.html");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);

   File defaultDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/path/my_text/");
    fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(defaultDirectory);
    File filesave = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(primaryStage);
    filesave.createNewFile();
    SaveFile(stringHtml, filesave);

}else{ File fileget = new File(fileread.getPath()); 
fileget.createNewFile();  
SaveFile(stringHtml, fileget);} }
```

SaveFile is

```
private void SaveFile(String content, File file){
try {Writer write = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter(file));
     write.write(content);
     write.close(); 
    } catch (IOException ex) {    }}
```

Comment: IT works correctly without if statement.

Comment: If the user doesn't choose a file to open at the beginning, what do you initialize `fileread` to? And can you explain what you mean by "this line gives me a NULL"? Do you mean it throws a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: What to do? He can choose file and don't. And if File fileread == "" || null then creates new file, with text he wrote at HTMLEditor. I thought only at that diraction, coz I novice.

Comment: Can you answer the questions in my previous comment?

Comment: YES, it gave me a NullPointerException, what it should - then why I choose if(){}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, if the user doesn't choose a file to open, then `fileread` will still be null. So you just need to test for that. Replace

```
if(fileread.getPath().equals("")||fileread.getPath() == null){

    // ...
}
```

with

```
if (fileread == null) {
    // ...
}
```

(or possibly

```
if (fileread == null || fileread.getPath().equals("") || fileread.getPath() == null) {
    // ...
}
```

though I don't really understand how either of the second two tests could evaulate to true).

Comment: @Kolia What do you mean "the same"??? It is impossible for `if (fileread == null)` to throw a null pointer exception, so you cannot possibly get the same result from that version of the code.

Comment: IT WORKS _ _ THANKS. NULL were in another section